# Redirect to error page when the browser back button hit?

Tags: javascript

I want to redirect to my Error page. If the user clicks the Back button in my web application.
I want to achieve this simply in Javascript. Do anyone knows?

Comment: In your `<body>` tag, do this `<body onunload="window.location("URL_of_your_error_page")">`. The `onunload` function is called when the user leaves the page.

Answer (score 2):

You can't due to a browser security restriction. A work around would be to check if the user navigates away from the page via `onbeforeunload` or `onunload` fire.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect to any page you like in Javascript with...

```
window.location.href = 'URL of the page you want to go to';
```

However, detecting if the browser's back button has been hit, to my knowledge, is not something that you can do.